# Devolver un mismo array sin el primer elemento

Tags: array, typescript

Tengo un método que devuelve un array pero no sé como hacer para que este me devuelva ese mismo array sin su primera posición, he estado usando el método `shift()` para lograrlo pero cuando lo uso me da error, muestro un código de ejemplo para emular la situación.

```
const secondElement = <T extends number |string>(arr: Array<T>): T[] => {
  return arr.shift();   //Error
}

const numArray: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const newNumArray = secondElement(numArray);
console.log(newNumArray);
```

El resultado de esto debería ser un arreglo sin el primer elemento, es decir:
`[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`.

Como puedo hacer para que el método deje de mostrar el primer elemento del arreglo?

Comment: Qué te parece si lo eliminas con [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Así `arr.splice(0, 1)`

Comment: Tendría el mismo problema, retornaría únicamente el elemento extraído (Es decir, el primer elemento). En ambos casos necesita primero modificar el arreglo y luego retornar el arreglo modificado.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato el método splice retorna los elementos eliminados pero modifica el array original, asi que solo basta con crear un nuevo array clonando ese en caso de no querer modificar el original

Comment: @Josbert, pero lo que quiero decir es que al retornar directamente `shift` o `splice` no retorna el arreglo modificado y es por eso que su código no funciona correctamente y devuelve el error. Lo que necesita retornar es ya el arreglo que se modificó después de `shift` o `splice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

No funciona porque `arr.shift()` te devuelve únicamente el primer elemento y al mismo tiempo modifica el arreglo original ([Lectura recomendada](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_shift.htm)).

Lo que necesitas hacer es, primero modificar el arreglo con `arr.shift()` y luego retornar `arr`

```
const secondElement = <T extends number |string>(arr: Array<T>): T[] => {
    arr.shift();
  return arr;
}

const numArray: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const newNumArray = secondElement(numArray);
console.log(newNumArray);
```

Esto devuelve:

```
[LOG]: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Otra forma sería con `splice` pero te devuelve los elementos extraídos y al mismo tiempo modifica el arreglo original, por lo que también tendrías que hacerlo en dos líneas

Ejemplo:

```
const secondElement = <T extends number |string>(arr: Array<T>): T[] => {
    arr.splice(0,1);
  return arr;
}

const numArray: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const newNumArray = secondElement(numArray);
console.log(newNumArray);
```

Si lo quisieras hacer en una sola línea podrías utilizar `slice()`:

```
const secondElement = <T extends number |string>(arr: Array<T>): T[] => {
  return arr.slice(1);
}

const numArray: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const newNumArray = secondElement(numArray);
console.log(newNumArray);
```

Comment: en el último caso el spread operator es innecesario: `const secondElement = arr => arr.slice(1);`

Comment: @PabloLozano, gracias por el comentario, ya lo modifiqué.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!, en verdad no creí que fuera algo tan sencillo, sobre todo había descartado modificar el array ```arr```, ya lo había intentado con